# How can I consume odata using json with c#?

Tags: c#, api, odata

I'm consuming an odata v2 api with c# / winRT. It works fine, but it's using xml as encoding format for both read and write requests. How can I make it use json instead?

I've already tried attaching an event handler to myDataSource.SendingRequest, and adding an "Accept" header, but the client-side library explicitly intercepts this and throws an exception. Also, I could not find any "Accept" property on the client side.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Please post the code where you are setting the `accept` header.

Comment: Are you using a specific client library? Have you walked through Phani's blog post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2012/04/26/developing-windows-8-metro-style-applications-that-consume-odata.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the WCF Data Services client library (as per Phani's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2012/04/26/developing-windows-8-metro-style-applications-that-consume-odata.aspx)), then this is currently not possible. The client library doesn't support JSON (yet).

If you really need to consume JSON you would need to use the ODataLib directly, which is not as "easy to use" as the WCF Data Services client, but it gives you more flexibility as well. ODataLib is the reader and writer for OData wire format. See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/14/introducing-the-odata-library.aspx) for a sample. The ODataLib for Metro itself - Microsoft.Data.OData.Metro should already be part of the VS 2012 RC release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an accept header to the request: 
'accept: application/json'

Comment: I knew that much, but my question is "How can I do this with the C# / WinRT client library?"